# Where does laravel-echo-server.json exit in laravel?

Tags: laravel

Where does laravel-echo-server.json exit in laravel?
I am just trying to broadcast an event.

Comment: Exit or exists? Not sure about your question...

Comment: exist sir aslkfjd

Comment: `BROADCAST_DRIVER` make null from `.env`

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't exists in Laravel. Laravel-echo-server is completely separate from your Laravel app. Well, they are made to work together, but the echo-server itself is not part of a default Laravel installation.

When initiating the Laravel-echo-server, the `laravel-echo-server.json` is created, inside the directory where you start running the echo-server. I have a setup where this file is located outside of my Laravel app files, because else it would conflict with Git versioning (local dev vs production server).

Answer (score 0):

Note that echo server isn't part of default Laravel packages. Add to your to your project with `npm install --save laravel-echo`

To create `laravel-echo-server.json` file execute on terminal:

```
./node_modules/.bin/laravel-echo-server init
```

Then follow the configuration wizard.